# Is iOS 4.2 faster than 4.1 (iPod Touch)?

Tags: ipod-touch, ios

I've read that iOS 4.2 is faster on the iPhone 3G -- they're making a big deal out of this.

Is this performance improvement limited to the 3G?  I have an iPod Touch 4gen and I'm wondering if I'll see any difference.

There's no features of iOS 4.2 that interest me, so I wouldn't bother with the upgrade, but if it also gave me improved performance, I might.

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like the "Find My iPhone" feature that used to be exclusive to MobileMe will be included free in this release.  So that's a plus.

Comment: brendan: I saw that, but I do not consider it a plus.  My iPod really does pretty much everything that I want right now, and the only thing that would convince me to upgrade to 4.2 would be performance.  The few features I would be interested in upgrading for are either not on Apple's radar (e.g., real Japanese handwriting recognition), or things Apple seems interested in not having (e.g., easy copying of movies).  That's why I'm asking about performance.

Comment: what do you mean by "easy copying of movies"? my movies sync over when i click the sync button.  if you are looking to sync movies in different formats you can use the free VLC app and you simply drag and drop movies into that.

Comment: Ryan: I mean, I've got some video on my iPod, somebody standing next to me has an iPod (or iPhone, or Android, or whatever), I want to send the video to her, we've both got wifi (tens-of-megabits at least), yet AFAICT there's no way to just send the video across.  We have to drive back to somebody's house and get a Mac/PC, iTunes, USB cable, file sharing, etc., involved.  Compared to most everything else the iPod does, I think it's pretty hard, and I think Apple wants to keep it hard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having used 4.2 GM on my iPhone 4 for a couple of weeks now I personally find it much much better at managing and minimising memory usage (regular checks using iStat). This should translate to better performance on older devices with limited RAM as less RAM to flash swapping will be required.